# Sintaxe correta de pesquisa LINQ em MVC

Tags: c#, .net, aplicação-web, mvc, linq

Montei uma aplicação com MVC que realiza uma consulta num banco de dados SQL e retorna ela como tabela, e agora quero adicionar uma barra de pesquisa à essa tela. Já montei a minha View "Index.cshtml" (com a barra de pesquisa incluída):

```
@model List<Pessoa>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Consulta de Pessoas";
}
@using ConsultaPessoas.Controllers;
@using ConsultaPessoas.Models
@using ConsultaPessoas.Controllers;

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style type="text/css">

    h1 {
        font-family: cursive;
        color: darkblue;
        padding: 5px;
        top: 0;
    }

    .tabela-pessoas {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 25px 0;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-family: cursive;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

        .tabela-pessoas thead tr {
            background-color: darkblue;
            text-align: center;
            color: ghostwhite;
            border-spacing: 1px;
        }

    th {
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }


    td {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .tabela-pessoas tbody tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    }

    .tabela-pessoas td:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
</style>



<h1>Consulta de Pessoas</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Pesquise pelo nome ou matrícula  : @Html.TextBox("Pesquisa")<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />
    </p>
}

<table class="tabela-pessoas">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px; padding-left:5px;">Matricula</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Unidade</th>
            <th>Cargo</th>
            <th>EstadoCivil</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Bairro</th>
            <th>Endereco</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>RG</th>
            <th>CEP</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Estabelecimento</th>
            <th>Codigo Centro Custo</th>
            <th>Descrição Centro de Custo</th>
            <th>Código Cargo</th>
            <th>Unidade de Lotação</th>
            <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
            <th>Data de Admissão</th>
            <th>Ramal</th>
            <th>Descrição Estabelecimento</th>
            <th>Data Desligamento</th>
            <th>Tipo Ramal</th>
            <th>Celular</th>
            <th>Situação Afastamento</th>
            <th style="border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;">Aviso Prévio</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (Pessoa pessoa in Model)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@pessoa.Matricula</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Login</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Nome</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Email</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Depto</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Unidade</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Cargo</td>
                <td>@pessoa.EstadoCivil</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Cidade</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Bairro</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Endereco</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Cpf</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Rg</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Cep</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Empresa</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Estabelecimento</td>
                <td>@pessoa.CodCentroCusto</td>
                <td>@pessoa.DescCC</td>
                <td>@pessoa.CodCargo</td>
                <td>@pessoa.UnidadeLotacao</td>
                <td>@pessoa.DataNascimento</td>
                <td>@pessoa.DataAdmissao</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Ramal</td>
                <td>@pessoa.DescEstabel</td>
                <td>@pessoa.DataDesligamento</td>
                <td>@pessoa.TipoRamal</td>
                <td>@pessoa.Celular</td>
                <td>@pessoa.SitAfast</td>
                <td>@pessoa.AvisPrev</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }


</table>
```

E esse é o meu Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ConsultaPessoas.Models;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace ConsultaPessoas.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var connectionString = "Data Source=BLABLABLA;Initial Catalog=XPTO;User ID=Usuario;Password=Senha";
            

            var model = new List<Pessoa>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM Pessoas";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var pessoa = new Pessoa();
                    pessoa.Matricula = rdr["matr"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Login = rdr["login"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Nome = rdr["nome"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Email = rdr["email"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Depto = rdr["dpto"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Unidade = rdr["unidd"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cargo = rdr["cargo"].ToString();
                    pessoa.EstadoCivil = rdr["estado_civil"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cidade = rdr["cidade"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Bairro = rdr["bairro"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Endereco = rdr["endereco"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cpf = rdr["cpf"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Rg = rdr["rg"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cep = rdr["cep"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Empresa = rdr["empresa"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Estabelecimento = rdr["estabelecimento"].ToString();
                    pessoa.CodCentroCusto = rdr["codigo_cc"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DescCC = rdr["descr_cc"].ToString();
                    pessoa.CodCargo = rdr["cod_cargo"].ToString();
                    pessoa.UnidadeLotacao = rdr["unid_lotacao"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataNascimento = rdr["dtnascimento"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataAdmissao = rdr["dtAdmissao"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Ramal = rdr["ramal"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DescEstabel = rdr["desc_estabel"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataDesligamento = rdr["dt_desligto"].ToString();
                    pessoa.TipoRamal = rdr["tipo_ramal"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Celular = rdr["celular"].ToString();
                    pessoa.SitAfast = rdr["SitAfast"].ToString();
                    pessoa.AvisPrev = rdr["AvisPrev"].ToString();
                    model.Add(pessoa);
                }

                return  View(model);
            }

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index (string pesquisa)
        {
            var search = from model in pesquisa select model;
            return View("Index", search);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema está nessa consulta LINQ no [HttpPost], a página carrega normalmente, porém quando eu clico no botão submit, recebo uma mensagem de erro indicando que o resultado da pesquisa não pode ser nulo, contudo acredito que a sintaxe que eu estou usando não está correta. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Que código é esse que importa Controller para View? (isso não pode bacana)

Comment: Olá! Desculpa, não entendi...qual código importa controller pra view?

Comment: `@using ConsultaPessoas.Controllers;` esse código não deve existir ai de maneira nenhuma!

Comment: A `View` só mostra dados a função é ver informação, em raros casos algum código peculiar de decisão, no máximo.

Comment: Obrigado por avisar, eu tinha colocado ali só pra fazer alguns testes, mas ele não é essencial para o funcionamento da aplicação, já removi!

Comment: Cada método em um Controller é independente, você utilizou um `model` que está sendo carregado no Index Get, no Index Post não tem carregamento, como são controles independentes essa variável precisa de uma nova carga de informação. Aquele Código na `Index` Get precisa ser refatorado para outra camada de serviço por exemplo ou camada de crud etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema inicial não é o `LINQ`, e como está sendo organizado o seu código. O seu código está escrito errado o `LINQ`, mas, é também desnecessário utiliza-lo, siga o exemplo mínimo criado por mim que resolve seu problema, pelo menos faz entender como deve ser organizado, existem melhores opções e o intuito principal é mostrar a separação de responsabilidade das camadas.

***Um exemplo:*** crie um camada de Serviço para te oferecer a qualquer momento a lista de pessoas:

```
public class ServicoPeople 
{
    private connectionString = "";
    public ServicoPeople()
    {
        connectionString = "Data Source=BLABLABLA;Initial Catalog=XPTO;User ID=Usuario;Password=Senha";
    }
    
    public List<People> Get(string pesquisa)
    {
        List<Pessoa> model = new List<Pessoa>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Pessoas";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
            {
                sql += " WHERE nome = @Nome ";              
            }           
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
            {               
                cmp.Parameters.Add("@Nome", pesquisa);
            }           
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var pessoa = new Pessoa();
                    pessoa.Matricula = rdr["matr"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Login = rdr["login"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Nome = rdr["nome"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Email = rdr["email"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Depto = rdr["dpto"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Unidade = rdr["unidd"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cargo = rdr["cargo"].ToString();
                    pessoa.EstadoCivil = rdr["estado_civil"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cidade = rdr["cidade"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Bairro = rdr["bairro"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Endereco = rdr["endereco"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cpf = rdr["cpf"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Rg = rdr["rg"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Cep = rdr["cep"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Empresa = rdr["empresa"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Estabelecimento = rdr["estabelecimento"].ToString();
                    pessoa.CodCentroCusto = rdr["codigo_cc"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DescCC = rdr["descr_cc"].ToString();
                    pessoa.CodCargo = rdr["cod_cargo"].ToString();
                    pessoa.UnidadeLotacao = rdr["unid_lotacao"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataNascimento = rdr["dtnascimento"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataAdmissao = rdr["dtAdmissao"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Ramal = rdr["ramal"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DescEstabel = rdr["desc_estabel"].ToString();
                    pessoa.DataDesligamento = rdr["dt_desligto"].ToString();
                    pessoa.TipoRamal = rdr["tipo_ramal"].ToString();
                    pessoa.Celular = rdr["celular"].ToString();
                    pessoa.SitAfast = rdr["SitAfast"].ToString();
                    pessoa.AvisPrev = rdr["AvisPrev"].ToString();
                    model.Add(pessoa);
                }
            }           
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

e no Controller:

```
namespace ConsultaPessoas.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ServicoPeople ServicoPeople { get; }
        public HomeController()
        {
            ServicoPeople = new ServicoPeople();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(ServicoPeople.Get(null));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index (string pesquisa)
        {           
            return View("Index", ServicoPeople.Get(pesquisa));
        }
    }
}
```

é um exemplo mais para organizar e ter esse código em disponibilidade em qualquer local da aplicação.

Poderia utilizar `ORM` (`Entity Framework`) e Dapper (`Micro ORM`) para não ter que fazer essas conversões ná mão.

Comment: Obrigado novic, vou implementar isso no meu código e validar se deu certo!

Comment: Vai dar certo e é assim que é feito (claro existem outras maneiras, mas, fui didatico) @PedroPerondini, se for resposta da sua pergunta

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação clara e objetiva Novic, funcionou da maneira que deveria, e agora além de tudo, o código ficou mais organizado, muito obrigado!